# CodeIgniter <DIV> format syntax

Tags: html, codeigniter

I have a template in `<table>` syntax, but now I want that to be converted into `<div>` format. Codeigniter Consist of a file called table.php which has functions to generate the table structure, but does the CI has any functions to generate `<div>` structure in our templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template library

1] [Ocular-Template-Library](http://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library)

2] [Comper Template Parser](http://parser.comper.sk/en/)

3] [Phil Sturgeon Template library](http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show)

4] [Bucket](http://backstack.ca/projects/bucket/)

I would like to recommend Phil Sturgeon's CodeIgniter Template.